# Are questions regarding FTC-specific Java problems on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Note: FTC stands for First Tech Challenge.

Are questions regarding FTC-specific Java problems on-topic?

In FTC, you use FTC's specialized libraries for interfacing with the hardware inside of their provided Android app source code, which you modify.

The reason I'm asking is that there isn't a single question about this here.

Are questions regarding this on-topic here?

Comment: Why not ? If it's about programming, and otherwise on-topic, I'd say specialized questions like this are fine. (But that's just my opinion..)

Comment: @JonasCz - They would be about programming, however only teams are allowed to buy the special hardware... so probably no one here would have it.